# (Play framework, Slick 3.0) Execute DB Operation and return a response depending on the result

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

What would be the best way to execute a DB operation and return a response in the controller depending on the result of the operation?

Example there is a DAO, call it `AccountDAO` which has a method

```scala
def insert(account: Account): Future[Account]
```

In my Service layer, `AccountService` I will do,

```scala
def create(account: Account) : Try[Future[Account]] = Try {
  accountDAO.insert(account)
}
```

Then in my controller

```scala
accountService.create(account) match {
   case Success(account) => // This will return a Future[Account]
                            // returns a created response
   case Failure(e) => // returns a 500 response
}
```

What is the better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `recover` in the `Future`. Here's example:

```
def create(account: Account) : Future[Account] = accountDAO.insert(account)
```

and in controller:

```
accountService.create(account).map{
   OK(Json.toJson(_)) //returns a response
}.recover {
    case ex => // returns a 500 response
}
```

I guess here's no "best" solution.